# Problems with css styling to FullCalendar event

Tags: css, fullcalendar

Newbie here (sorry!) - have searched for a solution for my FullCalendar issues and I am not getting anywhere.

I am trying to do some styling for my google calendar for my business website:  http://www.pilatesintuition.co.uk/test/pilates-classes.html

1. I have the background colour and text colour that I want (I changed the css file), however, when I click on the event on my test site, it goes completely white and nothing can be seen.  I don't want it to go white when I click on it.  I've looked through the css code and cannot see what I need to change to stop this.
2. Is there a way to apply a different background colour via css to the event if someone hovers over it?
3. Also, how do I move up the text where it says the date (Aug 11 - 15 2014) at the top so that it is level with the forward/back buttons.
4. Finally, I would like to see all the text of the event when in week view (i.e. I want to see '6pm' instead of currently '6p' - yes I know I've got a narrow calendar.  But is there a way to fit all of the text into the cell?  I have added this to my css:

.fc-event { height: 5em; }

which hasn't resolved the issue of showing all the text.

I am not a programmer or coder, so please forgive me for my ignorance and I hope I am not breaching any rules with this post.  I have just been told off on another FullCalendar related post I put up on this site - I don't know where else to ask FullCalendar questions as the author of FullCalendar said to post support questions on this site.

Thanks in advance everyone.
Josie

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using an active selector.

```
a:active {
background: none;
}
```

change to `background:#900` or just get rid of the rule.

2) yes use the `:hover` selector [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

3) Quick lazy fix, `margin-top:-3px` lines it up for me.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

1. The css code you have referred to above is not in the fullcalendar.css file - is there something in there that I need to change instead?

2. I will look into this one.

3. This works, so thanks :-)